# postgresql query optimization, time conversion

Tags: postgresql, function, date, query-optimization

```
SELECT to_char(to_timestamp(coalesce( 
    case position('.' in a.gen_time_of_admission) 
    when 0
    then
    to_char(to_timestamp(a.gen_time_of_admission,'hh24:mi'), 'HH12:MI PM' )
    else
    to_char(to_timestamp(trunc(to_number(a.gen_time_of_admission, '99D99999999')*24 , 0)||':'||
                          cast(trunc( ( (to_number(a.gen_time_of_admission, '99D99999999')*24) -  
                                  trunc(to_number(a.gen_time_of_admission, '99D99999999')*24 , 0)) * 60)
                               as text),
                 'HH24:MI'),'HH12:MI PM' )
    end,substr(a.api_admission_date,length(a.api_admission_date)-8,9)
),'HH12:MI PM'),'HH24:MI') from <table_a>;
```

This query is taking a lot of time due to multiple functionality and table having 6 million records.

Is there any way to get same result without using multiple functionality ?

0.720833333  is value in table of varchar datatype and we want format of HH:MM format. (ex: 0.720833333 convert to 17:18).

Comment: Your table is broken by design. Don't store timestamps as numbers.

Comment: Fix your data model and use the best matching data types: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype.html

Comment: Your SELECT statement contains no WHERE filters, so it necessarily must return all six million rows from your table. That takes time.

Comment: You showed us an expression to convert that `'0.72083333'` stuff to a time of day.  It may be possible to simplify that expression, but only if you tell us more about those text strings. Are they floating-point numbers which are fractions of 24 hours? (That's how Oracle represents time internally, FWIW.) And what do you mean by "multiple functionality"? Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

Just replacing all of the `to_number(a.gen_time_of_admission, '99D99999999')` with `a.gen_time_of_admission::numeric` should speed it up several times, and I think it will produce identical answers, at least with the single (incomplete) example you give.  But if the input is malformatted, it might provide answers when the other form will throw errors.

There are probably better ways to do what ever it is that this monstrosity is doing.